# Forms Authentication The virtual path '/Login.aspx' maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had an issue (asp.net 3.5):
when navigation to https://mypage.net it redirected me to https://mypage.net/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f which did't allow to login (because of ReturnUrl=%2f).

To solve this I have changed my global.aspx Application_BeginRequest:

```
     protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // redirect user from http to https
        if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }

        // I HAVE ADDED THESE LINES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if (Request.AppRelativen aCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Login.aspx");
    }
```

Now it seems to work perfect, but not.

THe problem is that I have another virtual application that is accessible via 
https://mypage.net/QA
If I enter directly  https://mypage.net/QA/login.aspx then everything is fine.

But if I enter https://mypage.net/QA then it says "The virtual path '/Login.aspx' maps to another application, which is not allowed."

- If I use https://mypage.net/QA it gives me an error
- If I use https://mypage.net/QA/ it doesn't give me an error and Login.aspx is loaded
- I have also tried to change global.aspx: 
  HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("**~/**Login.aspx");
  But in this case, when I anter https://mypage.net/qa Application thinks that I am in https://mypage.net and not virtual application QA.

How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this to route things logically rather than to physical files

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name:        RegisterRoutes
    // Purpose:     Register the routes for the site.
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/errorlog.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Base", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Base", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name:        Application_Start
    // Purpose:     The application start event handler.
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        InitSquishIt();
    }
```